# Improper integral doubt

Tags: improper-integrals

I have to study the convergence of the following improper integral
$$\int_0^{+\infty} \frac{x^\alpha \sinh(\beta x)}{(\sinh(x))^\gamma}dx$$

So I split it
$$\int_0^a \frac{x^\alpha \sinh(\beta x)}{(\sinh(x))^\gamma}dx + \int_a^{+\infty} \frac{x^\alpha \sinh(\beta x)}{(\sinh(x))^\gamma}dx$$
the first is asymptotic to
$$\frac{\beta x^{\alpha+1}}{x^\gamma}=\frac{\beta}{x^{\gamma - \alpha -1}} $$
so it for $\beta=0$ converges, for $\gamma \ge \alpha +2$ diverges and for $\gamma< \alpha +2$ converges.

The second is asymptotic to
$$x^\alpha\frac{e^{x(\beta - \gamma)}}{2^{1-\gamma}} $$
Is that correct?

Comment: Yes, why do you have a doubt?

Comment: My doubt is for which $\alpha, \beta, \gamma$ the second integral converges

Comment: I forgot that your asymptotic is incorrect if $\beta\le 0$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The second integral is equal to $0$ if $\beta = 0$, otherwise it is asymptotic to
\begin{equation}
\text{sgn}(\beta)\frac{x^\alpha e^{(|\beta| -\gamma) x}}{2^{1-\gamma}}
\end{equation}
Hence it converges if $|\beta| -\gamma < 0$ or if $|\beta|-\gamma=0$ and $\alpha < -1$.